# NG0201: No provider for t found

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I am trying to use a directive on one of my Angular components.  Please help resolve the following error:

```
core.mjs:6494 ERROR Error: NG0201: No provider for t found
    at F (core.mjs:254:11)
    at kn (core.mjs:3411:21)
    at Module.Fc (core.mjs:14433:12)
    at n.ɵfac [as factory] (environment-permission.directive.ts:9:44)
    at mi (core.mjs:3574:44)
    at Jv (core.mjs:10332:27)
    at Ah (core.mjs:9661:5)
    at Module.id (core.mjs:14578:9)
    at no (asset-list.component.html:37:5)
    at Dp (core.mjs:9632:9)
```

Directive code:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appEnvPermission]'
})
export class EnvironmentPermissionDirective {
  private permission$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);

  @Input()
  set appEnvPermission(permission: string) {
    this.permission$.next(permission);
  }

  constructor(
    templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    configService: ConfigurationService,
    permissionService: PermissionService,
  ) {
    combineLatest([configService.getEnvironment(), this.permission$ ]).subscribe({
      next: ([ env, permission ]) => {
        viewContainer.clear();
        if (permissionService.hasEnvPermission(env.name, permission)) {
          viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(templateRef);
        }
      },
      error: err => {
        viewContainer.clear();
        // viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(templateRef);
      },
    });
  }
}
```

How the directive is currently being used in the AssetListComponent:

```
    <div [appEnvPermission]="'asset.download'" *ngIf="!isAssetView()" class="my-auto">
```

and the AssetRevisionsComponent:

```
<div [appEnvPermission]="'asset.download'" class="my-auto mx-3" *ngIf="configService.getCurrentEnvironment().upload">
```

Component belongs to AssetsModule:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AssetListComponent,
    AssetRevisionsComponent,
 ...
  ],
  imports: [
    SharedModule,
...
  ],
})
export class AssetsModule { }
```

AssetsModule imports SharedModule, which declares and exports the EnvironmentPermissionDirective as follows:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
    EnvironmentPermissionDirective
  ],
  imports: [
...
  ],
  exports: [
...
    EnvironmentPermissionDirective
  ],
  providers: [
    DatePipe,
    DecimalPipe,
    CreateConfigSetRequestService,
    CreateMasterSetRequestService,
    ReplicateApiService,
    ModelPersistenceService,
    SchedulePersistenceService,
    CreateScheduleRequestService,
    CanDeactivateGuard,
  ],
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The error is pointing to line 9 at the directive I think... what do you have in there? looks like the directive is waiting for a parameter?

Comment: line 9 of the directive is simply:
```export class EnvironmentPermissionDirective {```

Comment: I think you didn't paste the full code here. Your exception happens in your directive itself.
I suggest that you have an constructor where you want to pass values (like: "'asset.download'"). There is maybee the error. The Angulars DI can't resolve that param here, because it thinks it must to instantiate a class here.

If you want to pass values as you do it in your code above, you must define a property that is named exactly as your directives class name.

Comment: I recommend to disable aot in the angular.json file for ng serve. Then you will have a not minimized output and your console errors have the correct classnames. :-)

Comment: I have now included full code for my directive in edit #1.

Comment: Where is your ConfigurationService and PermissionService provided? InRoot? If not, it should be also provided in the shared modules.

Comment: Please ensure, that you can work with not minimized code when you run `ng serve`. When it is not minimized, you get a much better error stacktrace in the console. Then you can see, what exactly can not provider in the constuctor injection.